# How to Terminate a C++ Function Called form C# Using p/invoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, break, terminate

I am calling a C++ function from C# using p/invoke, this function has an infinite loop (capturing frames to a file) which should be broken when an event is happened in C#.

How can I break that loop (which terminates that function)?

I tried to run this function in a thread in C#, and abort that thread when termination is needed. **But the abort function didn't work**.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(myMethod);
thread.Start();

// to terminate the function
thread.Abort();     //didn't respond
```

Comment: Can you modify the C++ function, or do you not have control over it?

Comment: I can modify it. Basically it records a video until the user hits the "Stop Recording" in C# GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the safest way is to do two things:

1. Expose another function named (eg) `StopRecording` that sets a global variable inside your native code
2. Inside your main function, check the value of the global at the start of every loop iteration to see if `StopRecording` has been called (and if so, break out of the loop)

This lets it terminate naturally without requiring any heavy-handed terminations.

Comment: Cancellation callback would be better

Comment: That's another fine choice, but probably more complicated than necessary for a simple case like this. P/Invoke signatures aside, the request was to stop when an event handler is called.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. Your approach is more complex because it forces the use of a second thread, or something like VB's `DoEvents`. A callback avoids all of that.

Comment: The code runs an infinite loop and cannot be run on the UI thread anyway. The callback solution requires two threads as well.

Comment: There are two threads in both cases - the UI thread (which must remain responsive so that it can receive the input event to stop processing, per the requirements of the problem) and the thread running the frame capture.

Comment: I can see any requirement stated that there's UI

Comment: Direct quote from comment on the question itself: ***Basically it records a video until the user hits the "Stop Recording" in C# GUI***

Comment: Thank you Peter, I used this solution.